# T-SQL Where Between X and Y Except Z

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a code that will provide in the where clause the codes between 210.0 – 229.9 EXCEPT for 225.0-225.9, 227.3, 227.4, 228.02, 228.1

How do I do this?

My where statement currently reads

```
    WHERE MisDxID BETWEEN '210.0'AND'224.%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE MisDxID BETWEEN 210.0 AND 229.9
    AND NOT MisDxID BETWEEN 225.0 AND 225.9
    AND MisDxID NOT IN (227.3, 227.4, 228.02, 228.1)
```